# opening a file that has spaces in its name

Tags: c++, string, stream, long-filenames

I have a problem opening files in C++ that has spaces in its name. For instance, to open the file `read me.txt`.

This is the code I have so far involving one command that reads a file and outputs the word count to the console:

```cxx
string choice, word, fname;
ifstream input;
int l, count = 0;

if(choice == "wc" || choice == "WC" || choice == "Wc")
{
    getline(cin, fname);
    input.open(fname.c_str());
    cout << fname << endl;
    if(input.fail())
    {
        cerr << " Error: failed to open the file: " << fname << endl;
        input.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        w = 0;
        while (input >> word)
           w++;
        input.close();
        count = w;
        cout << fname << " has a Word Count of: " << count << " words \n" << endl;
    }
}
```

I know that the stream function `c_str()` cannot read more than one string after a space. I was thinking of using substring but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: `c_str()` does't care about spaces... what's the problem here?

Comment: There are some obvious(?) errors in your code that prevent it from compiling (e.g. `out` instead of `cout` in the last line, `w` is nowhere defined, etc.). Please provide working code. Other than that if I "fix" your code to the best I know, it does handle filenames with spaces it seems.

Comment: How about a little bit of debugging...  Like `cout << "About to open [" << fname << "]\n";`  You know, to make sure your string is what you think it is.

Comment: Does "getline" function supports std::string as input?

Comment: How about when `choice` is `"wC"`? :)

Comment: When the open fail, you can use `errno` and e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

did you try this(http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/39687):

In a literal string the `\` character is interpreted as an escape code to allow you to embed characters that otherwise cannot be entered or are non-printable. For example to embed a newline in a literal string you cannot just hit the Enter key while typing the literal string because the editor would respond by actually starting a new line. So instead you type "`\n`", i.e., "`This is on the first line \n This is on the second line`". To enter a '`\`' character you need to escape it by entering two slashes. The first slash is the escape character and the second slash is the slash character being embedded.

example: `C:\\Program Files\\filename.txt`

EDIT:
The user does not enter the escape characters just the file name. The program then has to deal with the spaces and the path backward slash. `\n` designates new line but it is made up of an escape character followed by the n character.

Comment: When entering text as a response to `getline`, the user certainly doesn't need to escape their string either. Or perhaps I misunderstood you? It is worth noting (if you edit your answer) that `'\n'` and `endl` is somewhat redundant.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. I copied and pasted that section of my code but somehow the c in cout didn't show up. And there is a bit of debugging in there when I typed cout << fname;                               My question is that when I used fname.c_str(); I was unable to open the file with spaces. e.g. blowing in the wind.txt cannot open...